# Propagate exit code from runuser command

Tags: linux, bash, user-permissions

I want to run the bash script, StartSomething.sh, as a specific user. I use **runuser** command for that. Also I want to know an exit code from this bash script. So I write an exit code to the file when the command is finished or interrupted. Here is the code:

```
runuser myuser -s /bin/bash -c "./StartSomething.sh --pidfile=${pidfile}; \
                                echo $? > ${statusfile};" &
sleep 5
pid=$(cat ${pidfile})

while ps -p ${pid} > /dev/null; do sleep 1; done
end=$(cat ${statusfile})
echo "End code: ${end}"
exit ${end}
```

Problem is that exit code is still 0, though bash script is interrupted. What can be wrong?

If I have separate file, start.sh, with this code:

`./StartSomething.sh --pidfile=${pidfile} 
echo $? > ${statusfile}`

and runuser command look like this:

`runuser myuser -s /bin/bash -c "./start.sh" &`

everything is working fine. I want to use first example without separate file. Can someone tell me what can be wrong? Is there better solution for this problem?

Comment: How do you interrupt the script?

Comment: I use kill -11 $(pgrep StartSomething.sh)

Comment: I think this cannot be solved without more information. Assuming that you set the variables `pidfile` and `statusfile` somewhere, what are their contents? What does `echo "End code: ${end}"` give you?

Comment: `Pidfile` and `statusfile` are set before this code. I think it's not important. `echo "End code: ${end}"` gives 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is to run the program in the background, and wait for it to finish, I think you could also use `wait` to get the return value (`runuser` passes it through, unless something exceptional happens):

```
runuser myuser ./StartSomething.sh --pidfile=${pidfile} &
pid=$!
# do something else
wait $!
echo "it returned $?"
```

or

```
runuser myuser ./StartSomething.sh --pidfile=${pidfile} &
pid=$!
echo -n "waiting"
while kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null; do
    echo -n "." 
    sleep 1
done
echo
wait $!
echo "it returned $?"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with escaping special character $. Correct command:

```
runuser myuser -s /bin/bash -c "./StartSomething.sh --pidfile=${pidfile}; \
                                echo \$? > ${statusfile};" &
```

Replace `$?` with `\$?`.